Upper bound on the finite sum of $\sum_j x^j/j!$
How can I derive an upper bound on the following finite summation,
\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{x^j}{j!},
\end{equation} where $0 < x$, in terms of $x$ and $k$ (it's perfectly fine to express it in terms of the Big-O notation)?

The answer depends heavily on the magnitude of $x$ and $k$.

If $S_k (x) = \sum_{j = 1}^k {\frac{{x^j }}{{j!}}}$ then $$
S_k (kx) = \frac{{{\rm e}^{kx} }}{2}{\mathop{\rm erfc}\nolimits}! \left( {(x - 1)\sqrt {\frac{{x - 1 - \log x}}{{(x - 1)^2 }}k} } \right) - 1 + \mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{{({\rm e}x)^k }}{{\sqrt k }}} \right).
$$

Well, $S = -1 + \frac{\mathrm{e}^x \Gamma(k+1,x)}{\Gamma(k+1)}$, where $\Gamma(a,b)$ is the incomplete gamma function.  Depending on what functions you permit in a tight bound, this may be as tight as it gets.

$$\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{x^j}{j!} < \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} = e^x.$$
Edit 2: Correction to the tighter bound. I realised that I made an elementary mistake when reindexing the sum below. Here is a better answer.
Again, $$S = e^x - 1 - \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Now, correctly reindexing, we have
$$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+k+1}}{(n+k+1)!} = x^{k+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{(n+k+1)!} < x^{k+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{(n)!} = x^{k+1}e^x.$$
So, we actually get a lower bound $S > (1-x^{k+1})e^x - 1$ which we can combine with the upper bound to get $$(1-x^{k+1})e^x - 1 < S < e^x - 1.$$
Note that the result below is still correct for sufficiently large $x$ (depending on $k$). This is because $x^{-(k+1)}e^x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Likewise, we can subtract any other decaying function.
The upper bound $e^x - 1$ is actually already quite sharp because, for $n \gg |x|$, $n! \gg x^n$ so the remainder makes a very small contribution (especially for larger $k$).

Note: The following is incorrect!
Edit: A possibly tighter bound.
We have $$e^x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{x^j}{j!} + \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + S + \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ Thus, $$S = e^x - 1 - \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ Now, $$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n-k-1}}{(n-k-1)!} = x^{-k-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-k-1)!}  > x^{-k-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = x^{-k-1}e^x.$$
Hence,
$$S = e^x - 1 - \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} < e^x - 1 - x^{-k-1}e^x = (1-x^{-k-1})e^x - 1.$$

Thank you for your answer. Yes, that's what I thought, but I'm looking into tighter bounds (that's why I asked for the bound in terms of both $x$ and $k$).

@mike Is this bound tight enough?

For all $n \in \left[ 2, N - 1 \right]$,
$$\sum_{k = n}^{N} \frac {{x}^{k}}{k!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{N - n} \frac {{x}^{n + k}}{\left( n + k \right)!} = \frac {{x}^{n}}{n!} \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{N - n} \frac {n! \, {x}^{k}}{\left( n + k \right)!},$$
where
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N - n} \frac {n! \, {x}^{k}}{\left( n + k \right)!} < \sum_{k = 0}^{N - n} \frac {{x}^{k}}{{n}^{k}} = \frac {{x}^{N - n + 1} - {n}^{N - n + 1}}{{n}^{N - n}\left( x  - n \right)},$$
so
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{N} \frac {{x}^{k}}{k!} < \boxed {\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac {{x}^{k}}{k!} + \frac {{x}^{n}}{n!} \cdot \frac {{x}^{N -n + 1} - {n}^{N - n + 1}}{{n}^{N - n}\left( x  - n \right)}}.$$
This bound is sharp when $\left| x \right| \ll n$, and is useful when $n \ll N$.
